# Function for reading a data file with comments and headers

Tags: function, spyder

I want to create a function for reading a data file which is similar to txt file. I have already written code to read it (skip comment lines etc.). Now I want to define a function out of it so I can read multiple files and extract data from them easily without needing to write code for each data file. [Here is a code for reading two files and I want to make it more efficient by creating a function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6PkI.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code to get an understanding of using the file path

```
import os

# Define the location of the directory
path =r"C:/Users/Aman/Documents/"

# Change the directory
os.chdir(path)

def read_files(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        print(file.read())

# Iterate over all the files in the directory
for file in os.listdir():
    if file.endswith('.txt'):
        # Create the filepath of particular file
        file_path =f"{path}/{file}"

read_files(file_path)
```